# Google Sheet Formula - Reformat data via cumulated formulas to have a specific table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this simplified spreadsheet ([link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vGmP6Rwz59xUkTsMdDsCU4BWJnWEdWsVFzrEAFw_F40/edit?usp=sharing)) containing answers from a survey in the sheet "Answers Survey".
In the sheet, "Analysis | Answers Survey", I would like to reformat these data in one formula (instead of 4 formulas as in my example) to obtain the same table than in the range "A100:J123".

Could you please help me to obtain this "special" formula ?
Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: `VSTACK()` combine all these formulas result into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a possible *[solution here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vGmP6Rwz59xUkTsMdDsCU4BWJnWEdWsVFzrEAFw_F40/edit#gid=910598030)* for you to test out:

```
=let(Σ;'Answers Survey'!A3:AA;
     Γ;sort(unique(filter(choosecols(Σ;1;2;6);index(Σ;;7)<>""));1;1;2;1;3;1);
     {Γ\byrow(Γ;lambda(Λ;bycol(switch(choosecols(Σ;7;8;9;10;11);"high";3;"medium";2;"low";1;"N/A";;;);lambda(avg_;round(average(ifna(filter(avg_;byrow(choosecols(Σ;1;2;6);lambda(z;join(;z)))=join(;Λ))));1)))))\
      byrow(Γ;lambda(Λ;bycol(choosecols(Σ;12;27);lambda(join_;textjoin(char(10);1;ifna(filter(join_;byrow(choosecols(Σ;1;2;6);lambda(z;join(;z)))=join(;Λ))))))))})
```

[image]

Comment: It is perfect and incredible to create a formula as this one. A dream for me will be to create this kind of formula in the coming months Thanks a lot